# Memory leak in C++ VScode with mingw-64 ,CRT: _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() not showing the memory leak

Tags: visual-studio-code, memory-leaks, mingw-w64, crtdbg.h

I am on windows 11 using VScode to run a C++ code with ming-w64.
I have installed ming-w64 following [all these steps](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

I am running a code that has a deliberate memory leak to see if there is a report by _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks().

this is my code:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include <iostream>
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
    // Replace _NORMAL_BLOCK with _CLIENT_BLOCK if you want the
    // allocations to be of _CLIENT_BLOCK type
#else
    #define DBG_NEW new
#endif

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
   _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
   _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
   
    int *i2 = new int(2);
    cout << "address of i2 :" << i2 << endl;
    bool check = _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    cout << "MEMORY check :" << check << endl;
    cout << "After CrtDumpMemoryLeaks" << endl;
}
```

This is the TERMINAL:

```
PS C:\Users\שראל\Desktop\C_proj\projects\helloworld>  & 'c:\Users\שראל\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.9.7\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-o0zd5lqu.up2' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-gva0ndx0.ycm' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-eec2m2xg.4x5' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-fakhxofs.oyp' '--dbgExe=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
address of i2 :0x190a9ff1a90
MEMORY check :0
After CrtDumpMemoryLeaks
```

And the OUTPUT is empty.
I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW apparently does not support crtdbg functions out of the box, study mingw64\include\crtdbg.h, all _Crt* functions are stubs